# Can someone help me align text next to an image?

Tags: css

I am struggling trying to get the text to sit next to the image, its just not happening, please can some one explain what im doing wrong here? much appreciated!

```css
    
    
    .alignright {
     float: right;
    }
    
    .source {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    .source img {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    
    .margin25 {
        margin:25px;
    }
```

```html
    <!--LEFT CONTAINER DIV-->
     <div style="float:left;width:40%;margin-left:2%;">
       <div class="source" style="width:20%;">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
       </div>
        <h1 class="alignright">Recommendations?</h1>
        <br />
       <h2 class="margin25">main text</h2>
     </div>
    <!--LEFT CONTAINER DIV-->
```

Comment: Try moving the `h1` *before* the image. Otherwise, it's just going to float right from where it currently is: below it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  tags instead of div with display:initial in all 3 tags (img, h1, h2) and in h1 and h2  span tag set the float property to right or left.

Answer (score 0):

**Just corrected what was needed :**

(click on full page in code snippet or else you will not see the difference with your own result)

```css
.wrap {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.alignright {
    display: inline;
    
}

.source {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}

.source img {
    width: 100%;
}


.margin25 {
    margin: 25px;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="source">
   <img src="../image/recomendbutton.jpg">
   </div>
    <h1 class="alignright">Recommendations?</h1>
    <br />
   <h2 class="margin25">main text</h2>
 </div>
```

Comment: its same as O.P output

Comment: open full page, preview does not give the proper disposition

Answer (score 0):

```css
  .alignright {
      margin-top:-40px;
      width: 77%;
      float: right;
  }
  .source {
      overflow: hidden;
      width: auto;
      height: 100%;
  }
  .source img {
      width: 100%;
  }
  .margin25 {
      margin:25px;
  }
```

```html
<!--LEFT CONTAINER DIV-->
<div style="float:left;width:40%;margin-left:2%;">
    <div class="source" style="width:20%;">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"><span>
           </div>
           <h1 class="alignright">Recommendations?</h1></span>

        <br />
         <h2 class="margin25">main text</h2>

    </div>
    <!--LEFT CONTAINER DIV-->
```